# SDL2 (C++) not all .png images render correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

*Note: I am using Legacy OpenGL*

So I have encountered a problem where only a few .png images get rendered correctly.

Here is an example screenshot of rendered game (Left: enemyRed.png, Right: (ship.png)):

[image: Screenshot of rendered game]

**Here is the code I use to load images:**

```
SpriteImage* SDLOpenGL::loadImage(std::string path) {
    SDL_Surface * surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    SpriteImage * image = new SpriteImage(&*surface);

    return image;
}
```

**Here is the SpriteImage class:**

```
SpriteImage::SpriteImage(SDL_Surface *surface) {
    this->surface = surface;
    this->TextureID = 0;
}

void SpriteImage::bind() {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            this->mode,
            this->surface->w,
            this->surface->h,
            0,
            this->mode,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            this->surface->pixels
            );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->TextureID);
}

int SpriteImage::getWidth() {
    return this->surface->w; 
}

int SpriteImage::getHeight() {
    return this->surface->h;
}
```

**Here is where I render the images:**

(note, `this->getCurrentImage()` returns a "SpriteImage")

```
void Sprite::draw(float delta) {
    this->getCurrentImage()->bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, this->getHeight());

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(this->getWidth(), this->getHeight());

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(this->getWidth(), 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    this->next();
}
```

Comment: Here are the images btw: http://imgur.com/a/a5zNW

Answer (score 1):

- The image that doesn't render has a width indivisible by four. You should use `glPixelStorei` with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` before `glTexImage2D` to specify alignment of your rows in memory -- which are probably unaligned (OpenGL assumes by default that they *are* four-byte aligned).
- You should first `glBindTexture` and *then* upload the data with `glTexImage2D`.
- Do you ever call to `glGenTextures`? You should initialize the `TextureID` with `glGenTextures`.
- You should not upload the texture each and every time you bind the texture. Instead upload it in the constructor, then to switch textures you only need to `glBindTexture` your `TextureID`.